# Deep learning - finetuning on top of Conv net model

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, imagenet

I am fine-tuning on top of image net model using Alexnet architecture. My data set is quite small (7 images per class without augmentation) . I have to drop last FC layer(`"FC8"`) weights but what about other fully connected layers. For `"FC6"` and `"FC7"` should I use weights from image net model or initialize from random?  Learning rate for all three FC layers is 5.

Answer (score 3):

with so few training examples i would recommend fixing wights of all layers (conv, fc6 and fc7) and use linear SVM to train the final layer. Most of SVM training packages and algorithms are using global convex optimization and may yield better results than SGD in this settings.